# How to fix user UI login?

Tags: 18.04, user-profile

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.
I am unable to login as UI User, but able to login terminal mode after ctrl + alt + F3. No error is showing. Getting black screen and again coming into user login screen normally.
I want to login as UI mode also. How to fix this.

Comment: No error. Getting black scree and again coming in to user login screen.

Comment: Check you have space in your $HOME (user directory), as if there is insufficient space in the $HOME (/home/$USER/ directory) the GUI workfiles cannot be created and the GUI session is ended & user logged out (no message), thus a login loop is experienced.  This doesn't impact text logins.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved with the update of workstation Graphic-card driver via terminal.